# htaccess mod_rewrite - reroute all urls to index except /admin

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm setting up a small set of rewrite rules in an htaccess file, where I want every url to go to a index.php file except for /admin which I want to redirect to admin.php. Not very familiar with mod_rewrite or regexp unfortunately.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^admin$ admin.php [L]
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This gives me an internal server error (not saying 500). Removing or uncommenting the admin rewrite makes it work.

Comment: Do you have access to the server error logs?

Comment: It's running locally. Where should I look for the logs? (MAMP Pro OSX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions need to be applied to the index.php rewrite rule, otherwise it causes a redirect loop. A `RewriteCond` only gets applied to the immediately following `RewriteRule` so the rule that routes everything to index has no conditions. Try just rearranging the lines:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^admin$ admin.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```